# nestjs-i18n blocks my local & JWT passport strategy

Tags: internationalization

I am working with nestjs. I implemented i18n from the following tutorial available on the [nestjs-i18][1]n

To my surprise when I add the following configurations in the app module it messes up with my passport JWT & local strategy.

```
I18nModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        fallbackLanguage: configService.get<string>('FALLBACK_LANGUAGE'), // e.g., 'en'/*  */
        parserOptions: {
          path: join(__dirname, '/i18n/'),
          watch: true,
        },
      }),
      parser: I18nJsonParser,
      inject: [ConfigService],
      resolvers: [
        {
          use: QueryResolver,
          options: ['lang', 'locale', 'l', 'Accept-Language'],
        },
      ],
    }),
```

I'm tried to use in service like :

```
constructor( private readonly i18n: I18nRequestScopeService,){}
if (!isOldPasswordValid) {
      throw new BadRequestException(
        await this.i18n.translate('exception.BAD_REQUEST.WRONG_OLD_PASSWORD', {
          args: { id: 1, username: 'Toon' },
        }),
      );
    }
```

but throw error :

```
Error: Unknown authentication strategy "jwt"
    at attempt (C:\my-projects\Node projects\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:190:39)
    at authenticate (C:\my-projects\Node projects\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:367:7)
    at C:\my-projects\Node projects\node_modules\@nestjs\passport\dist\auth.guard.js:91:3
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at C:\my-projects\Node projects\node_modules\@nestjs\passport\dist\auth.guard.js:83:83
    at JwtAuthGuard.<anonymous> (C:\my-projects\Node projects\node_modules\@nestjs\passport\dist\auth.guard.js:49:36)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\my-projects\Node projects\node_modules\@nestjs\passport\dist\auth.guard.js:20:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\my-projects\Node projects\node_modules\@nestjs\passport\dist\auth.guard.js:16:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `I18nService` instead of `I18nRequestScopeService`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late, but you have to use module reference to inject user service in your jwt strategy (I assume you use such a service), as described [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref#getting-current-sub-tree). An example from my project:

```js
@Injectable
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private moduleRef: ModuleRef) {
    super({
      passReqToCallback: true,
      // ...
    })
  }

  async validate(request: Request, payload: unknown) {
    const contextId = ContextIdFactory.getByRequest(request);
    const userService = await this.moduleRef.resolve(UserService, contextId, { strict: false });
    // now you can use user service and the error will be gone
  }
}
```